# Search SQL table for value, lookup another value in that record and replace with value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a script on a SQL table that will search the table for the users supervisor and then replace the supervisor value with the fullname value. How can I do this? I am using MSSQL and have one table containing this data.

```
Before:

fullname,username,supervisor
Timothy Dalton,tdalton,rmoore
Pierce Brosnan,pbrosnan,rmoore
Sean Connery,sconnery,rmoore
Roger Moore,rmoore,dcraig
Daniel Craig,dcraig,

After script:

fullname,username,supervisor
Timothy Dalton,tdalton,Roger Moore
Pierce Brosnan,pbrosnan,Roger Moore
Sean Connery,sconnery,Roger Moore
Roger Moore,rmoore,Daniel Craig
Daniel Craig,dcraig,
```

Thanks

Comment: About screenshots in questions.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Update t1
    set t1.supervisor = t2.Fullname
from YourTable t1 
    join YourTable t2 on t1.supervisor = t2.username
```

This code hasn't been tested ... so make sure to backup table before using it

Comment: Hi, Sorry to ask but what do t1 and t2 represent? Are these variables? I don't often use SQL as you can tell.

Comment: @JamesTheBiker These are temporary names given to tables. In sql it is called as Alias

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query. 
Please note that below query will fail if there are `multiple supervisors with same last name and first name starts with same character`.
(for example if the `supervisor` is `rmoore` and there are `Roger Moore` and `Royal Moore` in `full name`,then the below query will update the supervisor with any of these names)

```
UPDATE y
SET y.supervisor=y1.fullname
FROM YourTable y
 JOIN YourTable y1
        ON y1.fullname like LEFT(y.supervisor,1)+'%'
             AND LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(y1.fullname,CHARINDEX(' ',y1.fullname),LEN(y1.fullname))))=LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(y.supervisor,2,LEN(y.supervisor))))
```